# .htaccess: Disallow PHP files to access anything outside their directory

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

On .htaccess how would I be able to disallow PHP files from accessing anything outside their directory, without using open_basebdir()?

Basically I'm going to generate .htaccess files into some dynamically created sub directories that cannot interact outside of themselves.

EDIT: Sorry I meant accessing, not moving.

Comment: The most secure way is chrooting Apache2 and PHP5. But It requires a bit of work...

Comment: Usually, it's better to move the restriction to one level above the webroot (the user's home directory for example). Otherwise you would be forced to place configuration files in a web-accessible folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are for Apache, not PHP.

What you want to do sounds more like the job of a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. 
I think I'd need to create a dynamic virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

php doesn't even know about the existence of your .htaccess files, so they can't avoid any script from moving any file

Comment: Sorry I meant stopping PHP files from accessing outside their directory not moving

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from #Root dir of your php file
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I should have worded my question better, sorry I meant stopping PHP files from accessing outside their directory not moving.